# Add event to all elements of a HTML input array and get the values in the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a row with 4 inputs:

```
<div id="productRow1" class="productRow">
    <input type="text" name="numbers[]">
    <input type="number" name="quantities[]">
    <input type="text" name="levels[]">
    <input type="number" name="prices[]">
</div>
```

I have an "Add Another Product" button and user can add another row by clicking that button. Generated row will be like this with the unique `div` `id`:

```
<div id="productRow2" class="productRow">
    <input type="text" name="numbers[]">
    <input type="number" name="quantities[]">
    <input type="text" name="levels[]">
    <input type="number" name="prices[]">
</div>
```

I have a wrapper div for all the rows like this:

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <div id="productRow1" class="productRow">...</div>
    <div id="productRow2" class="productRow">...</div>
    ...
</div>
```

How I add new rows dynamically with the unique `div row id` when the "Add Another Product" button is clicked:

```
var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap");
$(wrapper).append('<div ' + divId + ' class="productRow"' + '>
                <input type="text" name="numbers[]"/>' +
                '<input type="number" name="quantities[]"/>' +
                '<input type="text" name="levels[]"/>' +
                '<input type="number" name="prices[]"/>');
```

Also I have another text box which should show the total price instantly. So I need to get the price data of each row after each row's price is entered by user. I tried to add an event to all of my `prices[]` fields like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('input[name="prices[]"]').blur(function () {
        alert('testAlert');
    });
});
```

But it didn't work. I also tried to add an `onblur` event to my existing and generated input fields to get the prices like this:

```
<input type="number" name="prices[]" onblur="calculatePrice()">
```

with the function:

```
function calculateTotal() {
    alert('testAlert');
    var prices = $('input[name="prices[]"]').map(function () {
        alert(this.value);
        return this.value;
    }).get();
}
```

I also tried specifying input field like this: `'input[name^="prices"]'` and adding the event like this:

```
$('input[name="prices[]"]').on('blur', function() {
    alert('testAlert');
});
```

And adding the event by class like this after I added `class='priceClass'` to my price input fields:

```
<input type="number" name="prices[]" class="priceClass">
$('.priceClass').on('blur', function() {
    alert('testAlert');
});
```

None of these triggered the event. So how can I add an event to all elements of a HTML input array and get the all values in the input array after the event is triggered?

Comment: If you're using jquery to add the new fields, you should be able to bind the function upon creation of the fields, no?

Comment: @pshep123, Can you show an example?

Comment: have a look at jQuery delegatation of events to child selectors, http://api.jquery.com/on/ . In effect, attach the `.on` to a parent element that is not dynamically added, but specify the selector you wish to have trigger the event. ie. `$('.container').on('blur','input[name="prices[]"]', function() {
    alert('testAlert');
});`

Comment: Where is your code that creates the new row? Post that and I / others can build on that.

Comment: @pshep123, Add new row functionality added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need something more like:

```js
$(function(){

function getVals(){
  var n = 0;
  $("input[name='prices[]']").each(function(i, e){
    n += +$(e).val();
  });
  return n;
}
$("input[name='prices[]']").change(function(){
  $('#out').html(getVals());
});
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <input type='number' name='prices[]' value='10' multiple='multiple' />
  <input type='number' name='prices[]' value='2' multiple='multiple' />
  <input type='number' name='prices[]' value='7' multiple='multiple' />
  <input type='number' name='prices[]' value='1' multiple='multiple' />
  <div id='out'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here you assign the event to a button. I need to assign the event to my fields. Event can be blur, change or something similar.

Comment: Hold on, I'll do that.